# Angular 2 router Error: Invalid configuration of route 'undefined'

Tags: angular, undefined, angular2-routing

I'm using the Angular 2 router 3.0.0-beta.2.

I cannot seem to get a single route to work, I have this error:

**"Error: Invalid configuration of route 'undefined': component, redirectTo, children must be provided"**

**main.ts**

```js
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment, appRouterProviders } from './app';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [appRouterProviders])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**app.routes.ts**

```js
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig}  from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './';

export const appRoutes:RouterConfig = [
  [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },{
     path: 'home',
     component: HomeComponent
  }]
];

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  ...appRoutes
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';

 @Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }    from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<h1>
  App Shell
</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to provide the correct relative path for the *HomeComponent* import:

instead of this:

`import {HomeComponent} from './';`

do this:

`import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';`

**app.routes.ts**

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig}  from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';  // you need to provide correct relative path

const appRoutes:RouterConfig = [                 //removed export
      {                                          // removed square bracket
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },{
         path: 'home',
         component: HomeComponent
      }
    ];


    export const appRouterProviders = [
      provideRouter(routes)
    ];
```

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent} from './app.component';     //please provide right path
import {appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';  // added 

bootstrap(AppComponent, [appRouterProviders])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: oh geez.. Copy and paste bug! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For future readers:

This error will also show if the Component in question is not registered on the module, and can be quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i forgot remove component from default route

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', component: MovieComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: MovieComponent }
```

Just remove **component: MovieComponent** from first line